# How to access ViewController class variable and function in collection which is inside of tableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ViewController` class embedded with `tableView` in which I created two `cells`

First:

```
class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//MARK:- IBOUTLETS
//MARK:-
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var categoryArray: [PopularCategories]! {
    didSet {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)
}

}
```

In which I created I created a `CollectionViewCell`.
And in my 2nd `TableViewCell` class I `reloaded` the `data` which is coming from  the `api`.

This is `collectionView` code inside `TableViewCell` class

```
extension CategoryTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return categoryArray.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CatergoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CatergoriesCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = categoryArray[indexPath.item].name
    cell.image.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: categoryArray[indexPath.item].image ), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholderSmall"))
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CatergoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CatergoriesCollectionViewCell
    collectionCellTapHandler?()
    let id = categoryArray[indexPath.item].id
   self.categroyID = id
    controller.categoryId = id
    controller.filterDataUsingMostPopularCategory(id: id, lat: Latitude, long: Longitude)
    print("Here I can access my view controller....\(controller.categoryId)")
    print(cell.nameLabel.text!, id)
}
}


}
```

Now what I want I need to call a function which is in my `ViewController` when  select a `collectionView` `cell` item. This the function in my `ViewController` class file I want to access when `collectionViewCell` is selected

```
class OneStopShopVC: TruckerConveyBaseVC {

    func searchDataFromFilteredApi() {

    let param: [String : Any] = ["lat": self.latitude, "lng": self.longitude, "title": selectedTitle, "category": "\(selectedCategory)"]
    print(param)
    CommonUtils.showHudWithNoInteraction(show: true)

    Alamofire.request(Constants.BASE_URL+"search_home_ads.php", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        CommonUtils.showHudWithNoInteraction(show: false)
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                print(json)
                if let ads_list = json["ads_list"]  as? [[String:Any]] {
                    self.adsListModel.removeAll()
                    let response = kSharedInstance.getArray(withDictionary: ads_list)
                    print(response)
                    self.adsListModel = response.map{ AdsListModel(with: $0) }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.reloadList()
                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(_):
            print("Error")
            break

        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is code inside UITableViewDataSource and Delegate

```
extension OneStopShopVC : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return Int.getInt(self.adsListModel.count)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return 181
    } else {
        return 121
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return cellConfig(indexPath)
}

private func cellConfig(_ indexpath : IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexpath.section == 0 {

        guard let cell = oneStopShopTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CategoryTableViewCell.cellIdentifier()) as? CategoryTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.categoryArray = popularCategories

        cell.collectionCellTapHandler = {[weak self] in
            self?.filterDataUsingMostPopularCategory(id: cell.categroyID, lat: Latitude, long: Longitude)
        }

        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    else {

        let cell = oneStopShopTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OneStopShopTableCell.cellIdentifier()) as! OneStopShopTableCell
        cell.lblPostTitle.text = String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].post_title)
        cell.lblPostedDate.text = String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].posted_date)
        cell.lblPostedExpDate.text = String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].posted_expired_date)
        cell.lblPostedDesc.text = String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].post_desc)
        cell.postedImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: adsListModel[indexpath.row].post_image ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
        let status = String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].status)
        if (status == "Publish") {
            cell.statusLabel.text = "Published"
            cell.statusLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)
        }
        else if(status == "Banned") {
            cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }
        else {
            cell.statusLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        }

        cell.priceLabel.text = "$\(String.getString(self.adsListModel[indexpath.row].price))"


        return cell
    }


  }
```

Conclusion: When I click on `CollectionViewCell` item in first `TableViewCell` class I want to reload the data of `SecondTableViewCell`.. For that I need to access `ViewController` function to reload data. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you have multiple options on how to solve this, you need to choose one of these based on different criteria.

The first option is as the answer before creating a closure function and assigns it to the cell from the viewController.

The second option is to implement a delegate pattern like this:

```
protocol MyDelegate:class {
    func doTheJob()
}

class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    //rest of the code...
    weak var myDelegate:MyDelegate? = nil

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myDelegate?.doTheJob()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
    cell.myDelegate = self
}
extension OneStopShopVC: MyDelegate {
    func doTheJob() {
    }
}
```

The third option can be to have one class which will in charge of such logic some kind of manager class. This class can be a singleton and you can instantiate from where you need it.

In general,  you have a lot of solutions for this. But you need to think what is your need and to separate the code in the best way. Think about MVC, MVVM, VIPER or whatever you follow what are the basic principles of separations.

P.S you using an instance of UITableViewCell which is a view, as a ViewController this should turn big red flag for you that your architecture is not okay.

Comment: Yah will try that too

Answer (score 1):

Use **`closure`** to handle this.

Create a `closure` named `collectionCellTapHandler` in `CategoryTableViewCell` and call it from `collectionView(_: didSelectItemAt:)` method.

```
class CategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    //rest of the code...
    var collectionCellTapHandler: (()->())?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionCellTapHandler?()
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've used a `closure` accepting 0 arguments. You can modify that as per your requirement.

Now set the `collectionCellTapHandler` in the `ViewController` in `UITableViewDataSource's` `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` method and call your custom method `callTheMethod()` from it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
    cell.collectionCellTapHandler = {[weak self] in
        self?.callTheMethod()
    }
    return cell
}

func callTheMethod() {
    print("Hello...")
}
```

Comment: OK let me try that

Comment: I am getting this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` while reloading tableView after clicking collectonView cell item

Comment: Have you updated the reuseIdentifier in tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)? Also, add the complete updated code that you've used.

Comment: Haven't you changed the didSelect method of collectionView?

Comment: Added the code of didSelect method of collectionView check it

Comment: Check the didSelect method you add in the question again. And why are you using dequeue in didSelect again? Try using the same code I did there and once you get that working, modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197713/discussion-between-wings-and-pgdev).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using `protocol` design pattern, define a `CategoryCollectionViewDelegate`  `protocol`

```
protocol CategoryCollectionViewDelegate {
     /// You can define parameters as per your need.
    func didSelectCategory(_ index: Int)
}
```

Now in CategoryTableViewCell

```
extension CategoryTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var delegate_collection: CategoryCollectionViewDelegate?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      self.delegate_collection. didSelectCategory(indexPath.item)
   }
}
```

Now in the `ViewController` in `UITableViewDataSource's` `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
   cell.delegate_collection = self
    return cell
}

 func didSelectCategory(_ index: Int){
    print("array item index \(index)")
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks it worked well but @m1sh0 gave the answer first so I have to choose his answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NotificationCenter` for this kind of flow. A notification dispatch mechanism that enables the broadcast of information to registered observers.
Click the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the viewcontroller in cellforrow in your tableview

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
cell.parentVC = self
return cell
```

then in you tableviewcell while loading collectionview you can similarly pass viewcontroller

```
cell.parentVC = parentVC
```

This works as i have implemented similar thing in my project.

Comment: Not getting your point can you explain more  and  don't understand this line `cell.parentVC = self
`. can you modify it using my code

Comment: just as a note on this solution, be careful with the references. Like this, you can create cycle reference and have a memory leak. Your reference should be weak in order to be okay. Still, it is not good practice for the child to have knowledge for the parent. Better to use the delegate pattern.